# Python: TemporaryFile returns empty string when read

Tags: python, django

I need to create a file from a string so I can use it as an attachment for an email in Django. After some Googling I found the tempfile module with TemporaryFile but it's not working as I expect.

the following code returns an empty string.

```
>>> f = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
>>> f.write('foobar')
>>> f.read()
''
```

Comment: Great question, as the Django docs don't mention this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs#handling-uploaded-files .  If you use a method like chunks() first, it won't call seek(0) when finished, causing any future calls to read() to fail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call read, it is trying to read from where it left off, which is at the end of the file. You need to jump to the beginning of the file before you read it:

```
f.seek(0)
f.read()
```

If you need to write again, you should jump to the end before writing if you don't want to overwrite your stuff:

```
f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
f.write('some stuff')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing an `f.seek(0)` to rewind to the beginning between the write and read. A `read()` call always leaves the “file pointer” (which is kind of the operating system's index finger, pointing to remember where in the file you are currently at) at the *end* of the data you have just written.

Comment: oops, looks like i was too slow with my answer :P

Comment: On the other hand, you got in a good detail about moving to the end before writing again, which while it wasn't part of the question is something nice for this questioner to know!

Answer (score 1):

if you have a string already in memory, you can use [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) or cStringIO to simulate file over string. This should be much faster as there will be no disk operations at all.