# For json "r+", why can't I do dump and load within the same "with" statement?

Tags: python, json

This gives me an error:

```
with open('username.json', "r+") as f:
    json.dump(current_contents, f)
    newlist= json.load(f)
print(newlist)



json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

This works:

```
with open('username.json', "r+") as f:
    json.dump(current_contents, f)

with open('username.json') as f:
    current_contents = json.load(f)
print(current_contents)
```

But I have to open up 2 'with' blocks to do it. What's the point of "r+" if it can't read and write within the same block?

Comment: You _can_ do both things, but you need to `seek()` to get back to the start of the file between them. Either reading or writing moves the location inside the file you're operating at; if your cursor is at the end of the file when you try to read, there's nothing between it and the end of the file so it always comes back empty.

Comment: `r+` makes more sense for binary files, where you might be reading and writing *fixed*-size blocks at arbitrary locations. The "blocks" in a text file correspond to lines, which typically don't have a fixed size. (That's why you use `\n` as a delimiter, rather than assuming a line is `N` characters/bytes long.

Comment: BTW, this is also the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444809/python-temporaryfile-returns-empty-string-when-read, despite TemporaryFile being used there and not here.

Comment: Thank you. the seek function works out great!